# Java Check if time in between 2 times

Tags: java, java-8

I have 24 hours timeslots define as below, the question is how to determine if a specific time is in between one of the timeslots. any suggestions?

example:

```
String time = "01:30";
the matched timeslot is:  _0100_0159



private String _0000_0059; <-- has an int value in it e.g 5
private String _0100_0159;
private String _0200_0259;
private String _0300_0359;
private String _0400_0459;
private String _0500_0559;
```

Comment: If it starts with `00`, it's under the first slot. If it starts with `01`, it's under 2nd. As long as you are getting a valid time as an input, it would work as expected.

Comment: You can also use formatted data structure `List<Pair<LocalTime, LocalTime>>` to hold the time slots. Parse the input time as LocalTime and iterate through the time slot to see if its between the start/end slot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by putting the timeslots into map and search that map

```
Map<String,String > timeSlots= new HashMap<>();
    
    timeSlots.put("0000_0059", obj.get_0000_0059());
    timeSlots.put("0100_0159", obj.get_0100_0159());
        
        for (Entry<String, String> e : timeSlots.entrySet()) {
            
            if(e.getKey().regionMatches(0, time, 0, 2)) {
               return e.getValue();
            }
        }
```

Comment: There is no reason to perform the same `time.substring(0, 2)` operation in every loop iteration, just moving the line before the `for` loop would avoid that. On the other hand, you can omit the `substring` operation completely by using `if(e.getKey().regionMatches(0, time, 0, 2)) …` to check whether both strings start with the same two chars.

Comment: @Holger good suggestion, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We have an industry-leading set of date-time classes in the *java.time* package. So no need to resort to string manipulation to solve your problem.

Fill a list with your hour slots. I assume you want generic 24-hours days. Of course days can actually be any length, greater or less than 24 hours. But for some purposes, 24-hour generic days can work.

Since you want entire hours, we do not need an end time. The end time is calculated by merely adding an hour.

```java
List< LocalTime > timeSlots = new ArrayList<>() ;
for( int hour = 0 ; hour < 24 ; hour ++ )
{
    LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( hour , 0 ) ;
    timeSlots.add( lt ) ;
}
```

Parse your input string as a `LocalTime`. Extract the hour. Given that our slots are entire hours, use the hour as a coincidental index into the list.

```java
String input = "01:30";
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse( input ) ;
int hourAsIndex = localTime.getHour() ;
LocalTime timeSlot = timeSlots.get( hourAsIndex ) ;
String output = "Your time slot is " + timeSlot + "/" + timeSlot.plusHours( 1 ) ;
```

If you really think about it, we do not even need the list of time slots. If the slots are entire hours, getting the hour of the input tells you the start and end. But I wrote this Answer assuming your project has more going on than disclosed in the Question.

```
LocalTime
.parse( "01:30" )
.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.HOURS )  // Start of hour 
.plusHours( 1 )                   // End of hour
```

Tip: Spans of time are generally best handled using the Half-Open approach where the start is inclusive while the end is exclusive. So, for example, `01:00/02:00` rather than `01:00/01:59`. This allows for the spans to neatly abut without gaps.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the thing is we have 24 hr time slots so I'm just trying to avoid the 24 if else statements.